# add listrow to empty listobject

Tags: vba, excel

With some VBA code in Excel I have an odd problem when adding a row to an empty listobject.  Does anyone know what is happening or how to fix it?  Here is the problem:

First I delete the contents of a listobject (table), using:

```
AListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
```

Then I have a loop that iteratively adds a row and fills it with data.  I add the row by using:

```
AListObject.ListRows.Add
```

Here is the odd behavior.  First, the code deletes the listobject's data:

```
AListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete
```

The immediate window shows `AListObject.ListRows.Count` equals `0`, so all rows are deleted.  Then I add a row:

```
 AListObject.ListRows.Add (first iteration)
```

Immediate window shows `AListObject.ListRows.Count` equals `2`, so the Add method created two rows, instead of one.  Furthermore, the data written to row 1 is lost.  Row 1 of the listobject (table) displays empty cells.

For the remaining iterations (2 to n) of the loop the ListRows.Add method works fine, creating only one row.  Writing data to those rows (2 to n) works fine as well.

Why does the first Add method, called when the listobject is empty, create two rows, and why can't I write to row 1?  This code previously worked fine, and it works fine in old back-up versions of my workbook.  Does anyone know why this is odd behavior occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the entirety of the code instead.

Answer (score 0):

JNevill, thanks for responding.  With some more persistence I solved the problem.  A filter was set, and calling AListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete when the filter was set caused the problem. The solution was to remove all filters prior to calling the delete method, as follows:

AListobject.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

AListObjct.DataBodyRange.Delete

Thanks again for responding, and if I have an occasion to to post again, I'll follow your advice and post the actual code.